# How to listen the voice from different source when the pyaudio code is deployed in different server?

Tags: python, pyaudio

Now I have written a python code which recognizes the speech. It works well in my personal laptop. Now i have deployed code in linux server and I have created a webservice for operation. How does the voice gets recognized when I simply call the webservice?

```
def voiceRecognize():
        #now = datetime.datetime.now()
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("Tell me something:")
            audio = r.listen(source)
            try:
                print("You said:- " + r.recognize_google(audio))
            except sr.UnknownValueError:
                print("Could not understand audio")
                engine.say('I didnt get that. Rerun the code')
                engine.runAndWait()
```

Comment: You need to send voice data in chunck to webservice from whatever device you are calling webservice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do we send the chunks through webservice in python? I couldnt get that. Also I cant find any method in SpeechRecognition module which supports audio stream .